# Exception or If/Else statement

Tags: c#, .net, exception, if-statement

I have a question about when to use an Exception or If/Else statement. 
In my situation i want to check if a DocumentNode is a TestNode. When it is a TestNode, I want to get the node.

I wrote two possible solutions for this below. The first solution thinks it is a TestNode and else it gives a Exception. The second solution
checks if it is a TestNode, then it executes approximately the same function to get the node. Can anyone tell me what is the best solution? Or is there
a better solution for this? Thanks, Peter.

*Sorry for my bad English..

```
private DocumentNode GetTestNode(IEnumerable<DocumentNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (DocumentNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.GetValueProperty().ToString() == "TestValue")
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
    throw new TestNodeNotFoundException("This is not a TestNode");
}

OR: 

private DocumentNode IsTestNode(IEnumerable<DocumentNode> nodes) 
{
    foreach (DocumentNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.GetValueProperty().ToString() == "TestValue")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private DocumentNode GetTestNode(IEnumerable<DocumentNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (DocumentNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.GetValueProperty().ToString() == "TestValue")
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better solution would be to use LINQ if you can. If you want an exception, you can use:

```
var node = nodes.Where(n => node.GetPropertyValue().ToString() == "TestValue")
                .First();
```

(You can also use `Single` if there should be exactly one such node.)

If you don't want an exception, use `FirstOrDefault` instead:

```
var node = nodes.Where(n => node.GetPropertyValue().ToString() == "TestValue")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then `node` will be null if there are no TestValue nodes.

To test for the presence of a test node, use `Any`

```
var isTest = nodes.Where(n => node.GetPropertyValue().ToString() == "TestValue")
                  .Any();
```

(Your final method won't currently compile, as it can reach the end without returning.)

Which is appropriate really depends on what you're trying to do. If the lack of a test node indicates a bug, then throwing an exception is appropriate. If not, using `null` to signal that is pretty reasonable, or you could use the `TryXXX` pattern to explicitly return a `bool` value, while saving the found node (if any) in an out parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clear explanation. I will try to use this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Is not having a testnode an exceptional circumstance that requires execution of that function to be halted and error handling to be done?

If so, then - yes, use an exception. If it's a fairly normal thing to happen and something you expect to occur then an exception is probably not the way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a .net land now :) Why not go the Linq way? Create an extension yielding `IEnumerable<DocumentNode>` on `IEnumerable<DocumentNode>`? This will later allow you to use other Linq operations on a subset of test nodes

```
public static IEnumerable<DocumentNode> GetTestNodes(this IEnumerable<DocumentNode> nodes)
{
    return nodes.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue().ToString() == "TestValue");
}

...
docnodes.GetTestNodes()....
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your program should handle errors gracefully.

Throwing and `Exception` should be done when the code has run into an unsurmountable problem and immediately stops, throwing the error conditions higher up the callstack in the hope someone else will be able to recover from the condition.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need to hope that recovery is possible. In a situation you don't understand (when some data really should be there but isn't, for example) it's often better to throw an exception and *stop* than to persevere and risk corrupting what data you *have* got.

Comment: I don't agree. There are situations where a subsystem might fail with an unforseen condition that results in an exception where the encompassing program might act on it to recover. Such as restarting the subsystem, switching to an alternative or something else.

Comment: Hence the word "necessarily". Yes, in some cases recovery is possible, desirable etc. But that's not *always* the case, and exceptions are entirely reasonable *even if the error can't actually be automatically recovered* IMO.

Comment: Hope doesn't translate to expectation-- but to delegation. The subsystem throws the exception because it does not know how to recover itself. If it can or cannot be recovered automatically by a higher level is beyond the scope of the subsystem which threw(?) the exception. And the question was when to throw an Exception or when to handle it without one. Exception when unrecoverable (by the subsystem) in my opinion.

Comment: I think we agree about when to throw it. I just don't think the subsystem needs to "hope" about anything.

Answer (score 0):

A smart rule of thumb is: Exceptions should be exceptional.

Throwing or not throwing an exception should not be that much of a code issue, as a logic issue. What is your context? Is it the end of the world if `DocumentNode` collection does not contain a test node? Can you proceed your processing if that is the case? It the test node is mandatory, and it will always be included, except in some exceptional circumstances, than, yes, do throw an exception.

But if the test node is optional, or is often missing, in general, if the scenario where there is no test node is not that unusual, then exceptions are a overkill, since nothing exceptional happened.